# Twitter For Websites : Full Profile Header

Tags: twitter, twitter-integration

On an old website that I built I embedded my entire Twitter Profile Header ( cover / name / avatar / statistics ) into the footer of the page.

I'd like to do the same but I have no idea how I did it before.

I've been to `https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/overview` and clicked on the `Timelines` link but it seems there is no option to display the header image like it used to. What's happened and is it possible to display your profile header image like you used to?

Comment: [This Twitter Dev page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-users-profile_banner) shows how to get a user's profile banner (which I'd assume includes the header image)... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Without an example of what it returns it's hard to tell, but I don't remember it being that technical, or using the API. It was more like a simple, `Embed This Users Timeline` from your actual public profile.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter may have changed their embed options since then. Currently you can embed either a timeline, a tweet or Twitter buttons -- for anything more than that, you'd need to use Twitter's [developer API](https://developer.twitter.com/).

Twitter will auto-generate the code for embedding the options above. All you need to do is enter the user's profile name on Twitter's [Publish page](https://publish.twitter.com/#) and select the relevant options. Copy the generated HTML and insert it in your site's HTML file.

Some related Twitter guides that might be useful:

- [Twitter for Websites overview](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/overview)
- [How to add Twitter buttons to your website](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-buttons)
- [How to embed a Tweet on your website or blog](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/how-to-embed-a-tweet)

Comment: Thanks. You're probably right - I heard that twitter had depreciated a few functions. Looking at it, I guess it's probably best not to rely too much on any third party plugin like the ones Twitter use, just in case of such changes in the near future.

Comment: @W.Eless Using the API is probably more stable. I doubt they deprecate API features or endpoints as often.